# Automatizando uma função each JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end, each

Estou com um problema ao automatizar uma função em JS / Jquery.
Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
        $('.tab-pane').each(function(index, el) {
          tipo = $(this).attr('id');
          $("#owl-carousel-" + tipo).owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            items: 1,
            dots: true
          });
          $('#owl-carousel-' + tipo + ' .owl-page').each(function(index, el) {
            numberTotal = index;
          });
          $('#numbertotal' + tipo).text(numberTotal + 1);


          // Custom Navigation Events
          $("#" + tipo + " .btn-next").click(function() {
            $("#owl-carousel-" + tipo).trigger('owl.next');
            verificaActive(tipo);
          });
          $("#" + tipo + " .btn-prev").click(function() {
            $("#owl-carousel-" + tipo).trigger('owl.prev');
            verificaActive(tipo);
          });
        });
```

Faço uma iteração em todas as divs que possuem a classe ".tab-pane" e pego o seu ID como parâmetro para o restante da função. Até aí tudo ok, o problema é na função de click, pois ele está atribuindo somente a última iteração e sobre escreve elas.

Alguém sabe uma forma de fazer isso sem pegar parâmetros do botão de click para que fique automatizado?

Desde já agradeço ;)

**EDIT**

@juniorNunes aqui está o HTML, terão outros blocos como esse alterando o ID.
O bloco de botões tem de ser um para cada slide e preciso através daquele script
adicionar as funções para alterar entre os slides.

Adicionei o "data-tipo" nos botões apenas para funcionar, porém desta forma terei que adicionar em todos os botões e para evitar erros caso esqueça ou algum erro de digitação o ideal seria pegar este tipo pelo Js apenas pelo ID da div pai.

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="central">
  <div class="owl-carousel" id="owl-carousel-central">
    <div class="item">
      <span>Slide 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Slide 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Slide 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="paginacao">
    <div class="btn-owl btn-first" data-tipo="central">
      <<</div>
        <div class="btn-owl btn-prev" data-tipo="central">
          <</div>

            <div class="contagem-slides">
              <span id="numbercurrentcentral"></span><span> de <span id="numbertotalcentral">8</span></span>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-owl btn-next" data-tipo="central">></div>
            <div class="btn-owl btn-last" data-tipo="central">>></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is SO portuguese, please translate your question to portuguese or post it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask . Welcome, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Voce ja tento fazer um `console.log(tipo)` so pra verificar se tipo ta certo, porque se tipo ta mudando de valor nao to vendo porque ia sobre escreve.

Comment: Opaaa, você pode postar o código HTML e dizer o que exatamente você quer que ocorra? pro pessoal te ajudar melhor.

Comment: @JoseRodrigues o tipo está corrento, tanto que o slide está funcionando que é é gerado na linha "$("#owl-carousel-"+tipo).owlCarousel({...".

Comment: @JuniorNunes tem sim cara claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se isso vai funcionar:

```
$('.tab-pane').each(function(index, el) {
  var id = $(el).prop('id');

  $(el).owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    nav:true,
    items:1,
    dots: true
  });

  $(el).find('.owl-page').each(function(index, elm) {
    numberTotal = index;    
  });

  $('#numbertotal'+id).text(numberTotal+1);

  // Custom Navigation Events
  $(el).find('.btn-next').click(function(){
    $("#owl-carousel-"+id).trigger('owl.next');
    verificaActive(id);
  });
  $(el).find('.btn-prev').click(function(){
    $("#owl-carousel-"+id).trigger('owl.prev');
    verificaActive(id);
  });
});
```

Comment: Funcionou meu caro, muito obrigado.
O problema estava no "$(el).find('.btn-next')", você sabe me dizer a diferença desta chamada para a que eu estava fazendo direto no elemento "$("#" + tipo + " .btn-prev")"?

Comment: @Wellingtonfjr eu diria que a diferença na verdade é na sua variável `tipo`, veja que no seu ela estava declarada em algum outro lugar então o escopo dela era maior que a função, e que no do JuniorNunes ele mudou a declaração dela, que no caso ele chamou de `id`, como ela está declarada dentro da função o escopo dela se resume apenas a essa função

Comment: @Wellingtonfjr o que estava errado era sua referência pra chegar nos botões: `.btn-next` e `.btn-prev` se você reparar antes de colocar esse botões você coloca um id que não existe, ele seria o valor da variável tipo (central). e de acordo com o seu html ele é inexistente.

Comment: Mas este id existe, ele não reconhece a variável "tipo" que criei no início do script?

Eu utilizei ela para criar o seletor, então isto "$("#" + tipo + " .btn-prev")" ficaria  assim "$("#central .btn-prev")", e o .btn-prev está dentro da div com id central.

Muito estranho.

Comment: Verdade, agora que eu reparei. Pode ser que as suas outras divs estejam com o mesmo id, e ele pode tá embolando isso durante a execução...